# MySQL Cluster Auto Installer Error: DLL Load Failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu-server, windows-server-2016, mysql-cluster

I am trying to install MySQL cluster. I installed mysql cluster gpl auto installer on windows with msi installer. mysql-cluster-gpl-7.5.7-winx64

I installed 3 ubuntu servers to use as nodes. I allow remote ssh connection permission for ubuntu servers. I got this error when I add a ubuntu server in the mysql cluster web interface.

[Define Cluster Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p96A.png)

[Define Hosts Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYPWz.png)

I installed python2.7, paramiko, pycrypto on the ubuntu server. But i get this error:

DLL Load Failed: The specified module could not be found.

Where am I doing wrong?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows we pack *everything* you need to run MCC together so I am a bit puzzled with "I installed python2.7, paramiko, pycrypto on the ubuntu server". Why would you install Python and its stuff on Ubuntu server? Remote node only needs SSH server for authentication. If you meant "on Windows localhost" than again, there is no need to install any of the Python stuff, everything's packaged.
Can you please clarify and also start Python web server with log level DEBUG (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-programs-ndb-setup-py.html or, on Windows, modifying setup.bat works too) so we get better look into error from back-end side.